# Error installing GRUB

Tags: installation, grub2

I'm in the process of reinstalling Ubuntu overwriting the previous OS because it wouldn't boot after updates. I'm doing it using a USB stick. Half way through the install it shows a message with the following error: It's not possible to install GRUB at `/dev/sdb`; `grub-install/dev/sdb failed`.

This is a fatal error. I think its trying to install it onto the USB stick (sdb)? I then have the option to chose another device to install the bootloader to `/dev/sda` ATA ST320LTO12-9WS14(320.1GB) or to `/dev/sda1`. There is also an option to continue without installing the bootloader or to cancel the installation. This is my first experience with Linux and Ubuntu!

This is a link to first question I asked to try to solve the first problem with Ubuntu not booting properly but that got to a dead end! [Ubuntu not booting properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183099/ubuntu-not-booting-properly) it has all the steps I took to get to this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The OP solved the problem (originally written as an edit to the question):

> Problem solved. I chose to install the bootloader to `/dev/sda` but
>   after the computer didn't boot at all. I booted using the USB and
>   started the reinstall process again, didn't get any errors and it's
>   working fine now.